# How to structure a navigation bar with background images?

Tags: html, css

I have  to make a horizontal navigation bar with five options. Each will have a icon to it. The list will be made using `ul`. I'm wondering how to give the icon for each option. Should I make five different CSS classes, each with an icon , and assign the classes to the `<a>` elements or is there some other way using lesser number of classes?
I'll be using a sprite sheet for the icons and using `background-position` to specify which icon to display.

Answer (score 0):

Check out fontawesome in google and you might find what you are looking for. Simply add the icon tag inside each **li** tag and you will be able to get the required result. Sprite sheets are old way of doing it, use **font icons**. :)..